# Adding score and highscore in swift

Tags: ios, swift

Im making this Quiz game with pictures on it.

Im trying to add score. Always when you press the right answer, you get one score and when you press wrong answer you must restart the game (that i have been done).

my problem is that where ever I'm trying to put this code, its giving all kind of errors.

So this is the code for highscore:

```
        Score++
        ScoreLabel.text = NSString(format: "Score: %i", Score)
        if (Score > HighScore){
            HighScore = Score
            HighScoreLabel.text = NSString(format: "HighScore : %i", HighScore)
```

and i have put that on this place to the code:

```
import UIKit
```

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet var QuestionImage : UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var QuestionLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var Button1: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var Button2: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var Button3: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var Button4: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var Restart: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var LabelEnd: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var ScoreLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var HighScoreLabel: UILabel!



var CorrectAnswer = String()



var Score = 0

var HighScore = 0

  override func viewDidLoad() {



    super.viewDidLoad()



    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.



    Hide()



    RandomQuestions()



    HideRestart()



}



override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {

    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.

    }



func RandomQuestions(){



    var RandomNumber = arc4random() % 2

    RandomNumber += 1

    switch(RandomNumber){



    case 1:

      QuestionImage.image = UIImage(named: (“image.jpg"))

     QuestionLabel.text = “question?"

        Button1.setTitle(“answer", forState: UIControlState.Normal)

        Button2.setTitle(“answer", forState: UIControlState.Normal)

        Button3.setTitle(“answer", forState: UIControlState.Normal)

        Button4.setTitle(“answer", forState: UIControlState.Normal)

        CorrectAnswer = "1"

        break





    case 2:

        QuestionImage.image = UIImage(named: (“image2.jpg"))

       QuestionLabel.text = “question?"

        Button1.setTitle(“answer", forState: UIControlState.Normal)

         Button2.setTitle(“answer", forState: UIControlState.Normal)

        Button3.setTitle(“answer", forState: UIControlState.Normal)

        Button4.setTitle(“answer", forState: UIControlState.Normal)

        CorrectAnswer = "3"



        break



        default:



        break

    }



}

    func Hide(){



    LabelEnd.hidden = true



}



func UnHide(){



    LabelEnd.hidden = false



}

   func HideButtons(){

    Button1.hidden = true



    Button2.hidden = true



    Button3.hidden = true



    Button4.hidden = true



}

  func HideRestart(){



    Restart.hidden = true

     }



func UnHideRestart(){



    Restart.hidden = false

     }



@IBAction func Button1Action(sender: AnyObject) {

        UnHide()

        if (CorrectAnswer == "1"){

        RandomQuestions()

        Hide()

        HideRestart()

        Score++
        ScoreLabel.text = NSString(format: "Score: %i", Score)
        if (Score > HighScore){
            HighScore = Score
            HighScoreLabel.text = NSString(format: "HighScore : %i", HighScore)




    }



    else{

        LabelEnd.text = "You are wrong!"

        HideButtons()

        UnHideRestart()

       }

   }



@IBAction func Button2Action(sender: AnyObject) {

    UnHide()

      if (CorrectAnswer == "2"){

      RandomQuestions()

        Hide()

        HideRestart()


        Score++
        ScoreLabel.text = NSString(format: "Score: %i", Score)
        if (Score > HighScore){
            HighScore = Score
            HighScoreLabel.text = NSString(format: "HighScore : %i", HighScore)

    }



    else{

        LabelEnd.text = "You are wrong!"

        HideButtons()

        UnHideRestart()



    }



}

@IBAction func Button3Action(sender: AnyObject) {



    UnHide()



    if (CorrectAnswer == "3"){

        RandomQuestions()

        Hide()

        HideRestart()


        Score++
        ScoreLabel.text = NSString(format: "Score: %i", Score)
        if (Score > HighScore){
            HighScore = Score
            HighScoreLabel.text = NSString(format: "HighScore : %i", HighScore)


    }



    else{



        LabelEnd.text = "You are wrong!"

        HideButtons()

        UnHideRestart()



    }

}

@IBAction func Button4Action(sender: AnyObject) {



    UnHide()

        if (CorrectAnswer == "4"){

       RandomQuestions()

        Hide()

        HideRestart()

        Score++
        ScoreLabel.text = NSString(format: "Score: %i", Score)
        if (Score > HighScore){
            HighScore = Score
            HighScoreLabel.text = NSString(format: "HighScore : %i", HighScore)


        }



    else{



        LabelEnd.text = "You are wrong!"

        HideButtons()

        UnHideRestart()



    }



}
```

}

So always when you press the right button its score and always when wrong, its giving a label "You are wrong!".

And there is these kind of cases for the questions and at the end there is the CorrectAnswer.

I have 4 answer buttons. I also have 2 View Controllers, other is the start screen and second is the game and i would like to get the highscore label on the start view and the score label to the game view.

Thank you very much forehand!

Comment: First things first, what is `CorrectAnswer`?

Comment: I add some more code to the question so now you can see whats the CorrectAnswer.

Comment: what kind of error you receive

Comment: _its giving all kind of errors_. What kind of errors? Compile-time? Runtime?

Comment: Swift Compiler errors mostly.

Answer (score 1):

All your `ButtonXAction` functions are missing their closing parentheses `)`. You've probably missed one line when copy-pasting...

Comment: I was trying to put the code without that line and it still gives Swift Compiler error that says "Expected declaration" and "Only instance methods can be declared 'IBAction'". Then it asks to delete the IBAction from the all ButtonActions and when i delete its still not working.

Comment: Not meant to be rude, but I would follow some Swift tutorials to get a grasp of the syntax and basic workings of the language. It helps to know what specific errors mean. That being said, we need more code to be able to find out what's going on.